# Python website log in: BIG-IP can not find session information in the request

Tags: python, session, cookies

I have written the following code to enter into a website through python programming. But for some reason I am facing a error:

**"Your session could not be established.

BIG-IP can not find session information in the request. This can happen because your browser restarted after an add-on was installed. If this occurred, click the link below to continue. This can also happen because cookies are disabled in your browser. If so, enable cookies in your browser and start a new session."**

My code(website, username and password hidden):

```
import sys
import re
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

login_url = "https://example.ex.com"

with requests.Session() as session:
    proxy_url = "http://{0}:{1}@proxy.blah.blah.com:[portnumber]".format('proxy_uid', 'proxy_password')
    session.proxies = {'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url}
    data = {
        'username': '_uname_',
        'password': '_Password_',
        'vhost': 'standard'
    }
    r = session.get(login_url)
    print r.cookies
    print r.headers
    r1 = session.post(login_url+'/my.policy', data=data)
    print r1.cookies
    print r1.headers
    print r1.reason
    with open("login.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(r1.content))
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the website normally (F12-Network etc), what appears in your response headers info?

There is likely a session cookie that you need to collect as your first step (probably using a get request) and then include that cookie in your own request headers when you submit your post request with username and password.

Comment: When I'm trying to call login url at first `r = session.get(login_url)
 print r.cookies` Im getting empty coookie  `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`. It would be helpful if you would include some example or code snippet

Comment: You are one step too early. You need to replicate the step of going to the main page url first. This is where you will get the session cookie. Then go to your login url, posting the session cookie. I can send you some example code using the requests lib later today or search youtube for "python requests login" and there are a couple of great demos on the subject.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you could benefit from the dev tools built into chrome, IE, Firefox as they will allow you to view the headers as you go through the steps and find your headers and session cookies. Again this is demonstrated in most of the youtube demos.